# Show property of eigenvectors on block triagular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

This is part 'a' of exercise 4.2.5 of the book Fundamentals Of matrix Computations 1st. ed.

$
A \in C^{nxn},\\
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
   A_{11} & A_{12}\\
   0 & A_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix},
$

$A$ is triangular

$
A_{11} \in C^{jxj} and A_{22} \in C^{kk}, j + k = n
$

a) If ($\lambda$, $u$) eigenpair of $A_{11}$, show that $\exists$ $w$ $\in$ $C^{k}$ such that ($\lambda, 
\begin{bmatrix}
   u\\
   w\\
\end{bmatrix}
$) autopair of A

It is previously proven that $\lambda$ eigenvalue of A if it is an eigenvalue of $A_{11}$. I understand that if $w$ = 0, the exercise is there, but I cannot get a general case: I know ($\lambda, v$) is eigenpair of A, but I cannot show v = 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
   u\\
   w\\
\end{bmatrix}
$.

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT:**

My idea for the solution was:

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
   A_{11} & A_{12}\\
   0 & A_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix},\\
v = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   u\\
   w\\
\end{bmatrix},\\
Av = \lambda v\\
$$
For the first $j$ rows:
$$
Av = \lambda b,\\
b = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   A_{11}[i] \cdot u + A_{12}[i] \cdot w\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
For the following rows:
$$
Av = \lambda c,\\
c = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \cdot u + A_{22}[k] \cdot w\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
Therefore: 
$$
v = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}[i] \cdot u + A_{12}[i] \cdot w\\
   0 \cdot u + A_{22}[k] \cdot w\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
Since we know $A_{11}v = \lambda v$, we can just simplify by saying w = 0.

That does show $\exists w$, but I am not 100% confident on this. Again, I would love to know if this is correct and a possible better path.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to prove. Do you want to show, that for any eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$ of $A$ there exist $u,w,\lambda$ such that $v=(u,w)^T$ and $(\lambda,u)$ is an eigenpair of $A_{11}$? You won't be able to prove this, since its not true.

Comment: @weee Sorry for the late reply. 

That is what I want to prove. The book says it is true. If you say $w = 0$, for example, you get the answer expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I had the chance to talk to a math professor in my university and showed him this question. He said my solution not accurately written but was almost correct, except for the final conclusion

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
   A_{11} & A_{12}\\
   0 & A_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix},\\
v = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   u\\
   w\\
\end{bmatrix},\\
Av = \lambda v\\
$$
For the first $j$ rows:
$$
Av = \lambda b,\\
b = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   A_{11}[i] \cdot u + A_{12}[i] \cdot w\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
For the following rows:
$$
Av = \lambda c,\\
c = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \cdot u + A_{22}[k] \cdot w\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
Therefore: 
$$
v = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}[i] \cdot u + A_{12}[i] \cdot w\\
   0 \cdot u + A_{22}[k] \cdot w\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
<s>Since we know $A_{11}v = \lambda v$, we can just simplify by saying w = 0.</s>

Instead, the correct was:
$$
A_{11} u = \lambda u\\
A_{11} u + A_{12} w = \lambda u\\
0 + A_{22} w = \lambda w
$$
which gives:
$$
A_{12}w = 0\\
A_{22}w = \lambda w
$$
Either $w$ = 0 or (($\lambda, w$) eigenpair of $A_{22}$ AND $A_{12}w = 0$[miracle]). Since $w$ = 0 is always valid, we showed there is always a $w$ such that ($\lambda, \begin{bmatrix}
   u\\
   w\\
\end{bmatrix},\\$) eigenpair of $A$.

We were both in a hurry so we might have still missed something. However, I think this looks better now